# Which Stack Exchange site has the highest upvote to downvote ratio? Which one has the lowest?

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics

I'm not sure if this is possible (maybe someone with the access to all the [site analytics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) can answer this question). Which Stack Exchange site has the highest upvote to downvote ratio? Which one has the lowest? Are there any reasons for why this is so?

Let's limit the sites to those which are public, so excluding sites which are still in private beta.

I hope an answer is out there!

Answer (score 12):

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/815203/upvote-downvote-ratio-per-site), [TEX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) has the highest upvote/downvote ratio: 70.57 upvotes for each downvote. [Islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com) has the lowest, only 2.29 upvotes for each downvote.

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results (site nvarchar(250)
                       , votetypeid int
                       , numberofvotes int);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union all'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , votetypeid
     , count(*)
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.votes
where votetypeid IN (2, 3) group by votetypeid '
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5
  and (name not like '%.Meta' or name = 'StackExchange.Meta')

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

select u.site,
  u.numberofvotes AS [# upvotes],
  d.numberofvotes AS [# downvotes],
  ROUND(CAST(u.numberofvotes AS FLOAT) / d.numberofvotes, 2) AS [U/D ratio]
  from #results as u
  inner join #results as d
  on u.site = d.site
  where u.votetypeid = 2
    and d.votetypeid = 3
  order by CAST(u.numberofvotes AS FLOAT) / d.numberofvotes desc

drop table #results
```

Note that SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning.

Comment: Wow this is very cool! I guess its up to the social scientists to posit why this is so.

Comment: Tough to say. Overall quality of posts could be a factor, as well as the ratio of users which are able to upvote vs. those who are able to downvote.

Comment: @Glorfindel My guess is it’s highly correlated with the local “eternal September”, whether that’s already occurs for each site, and if so how long ago it started. A good proxy would be size and age of each site. The smaller and newer a site is, the more friendly I’d expect it to be. Once the public (aka “unwashed masses”) have flooded in, I expect the downvotes to swiftly follow.

Comment: [Replace "Nintendo" by "TeX"](https://xkcd.com/186/)

Comment: @PloniAlmoni It's likely because Islam is a religion which, like others, contains a lot of subjective opinions and mutually-incompatible views. This leads to substantial disagreements.