# Conditions for keeping reputation in case of post deletion

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, deleted-posts

In an answer for [Deleted Question: Impact to Reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176479/259305), it's quoted that reputation earned from *posts*

1. with score ≥ 3
2. "visible on the site for ≥ 60 days"

would be retained despite their deletion.

I clicked on the [linked FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/259305) and the following text puzzled me.

> ## Are there exceptions?
>
> Occasionally some exceptions are made. Often, these exceptions come in to play when:
>
> - All *answers* are *more than 60 days old*, and have 3, or higher score (the standard prevention against deleting answered questions is there so answerers don't lose rep, but if all answers have been *visible for at least 60 days* and have a score of +3 or higher, this is a moot point since their rep will be kept)

To concisely write my questions, I refer

- "post with ≥ 60 days old" as "aged post"; and
- "post with score ≥ 3" as "highly-voted post".

As a participant of Math.SE, I come up *naturally* with the following questions.

1. What is the *scope* of these two criteria?  For *any* type of posts or for answers *only*?
2. Can somebody help me to understand "All answers are more than 60 days old"?  I find *two* ways in reading this.

   - "when all answers [to the deleted question] are more than 60 days old": that seems bizarre since a highly-voted, aged question might attract new answers with score < 3.
   - "when all [deleted] answers [which] are more than 60 days old": this seems more sensible, but what about deleted, aged, highly-voted questions?
3. "visible on the site for ≥ 60 days" is *different* from "60 days old".  Which one is correct?

   - The later means the time elapsed after post creation.
   - The former is duration of deletion substracted from the later.
4. In the quoted [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) answer, it's written "> 60 days" outside the bracket, and "≥ 60 days" inside the bracket.  Which one is correct?
5. How is the number of days for which a post is visible calculated in case of multiple un-/deletion cycles?  Here're two possible ways:

   - We calculate duration between an undeletion and a deletion in (milli)seconds and add them up *before* rounding them (up/down/off?) to an integer; or
   - We calculate each duration, and round it (up/down/off?) to an integer *before* adding them up.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually very simple: you get to keep the reputation if the post

- has a score of 3 or higher
- is deleted 60 days (1440 hours, 86400 minutes) later than its creation timestamp.

It doesn't matter whether it's an answer or a question, how long it actually has been visible, or *even how long it was on the site*: I recently permanently earned [70 reputation on Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/348/glorfindel?tab=reputation) because [a Meta Stack Exchange post of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307655/295232) scoring 7 that was more than 60 days old was [migrated there by accident and reversed two minutes later](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/307654/revisions).

Comment: In case anyone's wondering how a post was migrated despite it being more than 60 days old: staff can bypass the restriction. I've so far not gotten a clear answer as to whether the system simply allows use of the normal tool by staff, or if some special dev route is required.