# Lost many reputation points because my answer was deleted - what to do now?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I answered a question on Mathematics Stack Exchange and gained around 80 reputation from it. This was the first time I gained points and earned a decent number of privileges.

But now that question was deleted and I lost so many points (almost 3/4 of my total). And so many privileges were gone too.

Is there something I can do?

Comment: You can ask a question on Mathematics meta, asking to have the question undeleted, **if** you have a good argument that the question is valuable, and deserves to be on the site.

Comment: I will add to the above comment that if the post was deleted recently, you can still find it: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948) If the question is worth undeleting, a reasonable place to ask for the undeletion might be here: [Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes (volume 07/2018 - today)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28692).

Comment: I don't know If the question is worth undeleting. However I had figured out a really amazing solution to it that a lot of users encourages and I got so many upvotes that gave me so much reputation. Thank you for your replies though. Appreciate it

Comment: And the question was not mine. Only the answer was.  The user whose question I had answered had deleted the question

Comment: The user can't delete the question themselves if it has a positively scoring answer (unless said user is a moderator, but that's highly unlikely).

Comment: I think you should've raised this on the local meta first, instead of going network-wide.

Comment: @Mast probably (I wouldn't mind if it is migrated) but it's a situation which could arise on other sites as well. Even my anecdote below could happen on another site (e.g. Puzzling).

Comment: FWIW, it's quite common for homework cheats to delete their question as soon as they get an answer, in an attempt to hide the evidence that they cheated. However, that doesn't seem to be the case here, since an asker cannot delete their question if it has any upvoted answers, as Glorfindel mentioned.

Comment: So isn't it unfair that all the time I spent on it is gone

Comment: @Glorfindel Here is the follow-up discussion in the room you have suggested: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352/2020/5/1 (Although some details about the question are mentioned there. Here is a link to the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3644316/if-f-mathbb-r-rightarrow-mathbb-r-such-that-fx2x2fx2-3x2-9x - however, currently visible only for 10k+ users and the users who posted the question or the answers.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- The post was deleted for a reason; if only your answer was deleted, there's probably a comment stating why it was deleted, and you can try to address that problem and subsequently flag the post for moderator attention. If the *question* was deleted, it probably [shouldn't have been answered to begin with](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

  - Speaking from personal experience, in 2017 I had posted [a Mathematics answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2093587/228959) scoring +15 which was deleted because the question was from an open competition. The question has been undeleted after the competition closed and I gained my reputation back. Now, seven months ago, three users voted to delete the question. No idea why, but [at least I got to keep my reputation this time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327541/295232) since the post was more than 60 days old.
- Write a good answer to another question. There are [plenty of unanswered questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I am currently actively answering any question that I am able to. And yes it was the question that got deleted, I don't know the reason. It was a majority of my reputation.

Comment: You still have enough reputation to chat, so you can enter [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) and ask why the question was deleted (if the comments don't indicate why). Otherwise, follow Martin's advice: asking for undeleting on Math.Meta. But justify objectively why it should be undeleted; "I lost a lot of rep" is not a good reason to undelete a question.

Comment: Could be a question from the under age user who's account was just deleted ...

Comment: @DavidPostill doesn't that just delete the user but not the question itself? Or does that depend on the question's (not the answer's) score?

Comment: @DavidPostill ["The system will automatically delete any post, regardless of score or answers to questions, when its owner's account is destroyed (only done for spammers and blatant trolls)."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/295232) The under age user's question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347309/295232) wasn't deleted either, and the posts they mention in that question still exist...

Comment: There are a few users (maybe 6) who are rampantly deleting questions on Math SE. They've been doing it for awhile now.