# Do we do more than "frown on" plagiarism?

Tags: feature-request, help-center, wording, plagiarism

I just realized that [How to reference material written by others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) reads as follows:

> [Plagiarism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your content being downvoted or deleted.

The wording "is frowned on" seems like it's too soft (and may be especially confusing for English learners). There are plenty of things that we frown on but those typically result in posts being edited with no further consequences for the user. For example, I frown on people using hyphens (-) where em-dashes (—) should be used. Can we change the wording to say simply "is not allowed"? (Also maybe also fix the hyphen thing while you're at it.)

Comment: Given the company's tolerance of unattributed GPT answers, which themselves are  effectively generated by probabilistic plagiarism, it seems like we do less than frown on it... we practically encourage it.

Comment: @ggorlen The tolerance is no longer there after the strike, I thought?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Right, it took 2 months of arm twisting, and I'm not certain they're authentic about it if not for force. I'm still seeing more GPT answers than ever, but now flags aren't handled as fast as they used to be before the strike, although maybe things are still getting up to speed. I'm hoping the damage isn't already done.

Comment: Even as someone with a substantial knowledge of English, this sounds like "you can plagiarize if you want, just note that others may not like it and downvote/delete vote your answer" to me, which is not true of course.

Comment: Apparently *"[most sites don't have any plagiarism at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381806/we-need-a-dedicated-plagiarism-flag#comment1313698_383588)"*.